# How to configure private docker image using Amazon Elastic Container Service Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, cloudbees

I am using plugin:
Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS)  to create Jenkins agents.
I want to configure in ECS agent templates section(from the “configureClouds/ “Jenkins page)  to pull private docker image. Which is based of jenkins/jnlp-agent
How do I configure it under “Docker Image” .
(For public docker images I just give “jenkins/jnlp-agent” under “Docker Image”)
Any pointers will be really helpful[image: ECS plugin options]

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'label1'
    }
    
    
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
              sh 'pwd'
            }
        }
    }
}
```